# Data is not stored in database eventhough API successfully passed in postman

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-api

I am trying to store a historical data through API from front-end(flutter). Below are the controller in laravel. When I ran my code in postman, it supposed to work, since the message "suksess add data" does appear when I sent a request and the date_checkIn, time_checkIn are all recorded as shown here https://paste.pics/f31592f51f63a5f77af77b0c0ad1e555. However, when I check in my database, the date_checkIn, time_checkIn, and location_checkIn column is NULL and only *staff_id*, created_at, updated_at column is recorded . As I try and repeat the request in postman but change location_checkIn, a new record appear in the attendance_record table showing the same result but now there are 2 of the *same* *staff_id* and also created_at and updated_at column is recorded.

I want to store the record everytime the user *clock in* from front-end(flutter). How do I fix this ?

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');

        // Retrieve current data
        $currentData = $users->toArray();

        // Store current data in attendance record table
        $attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
        $attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
        $attendanceRecord->save();

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

        $users->save();

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Comment: Question : Should the location_checkIn, time_checkIn and date_checkIn be linked to `$attendanceRecord` and not `$users` ?? (I ask this because the check in data should be linked to attendanceRecord, not to user, right ? (although I do not know your db schema , but it seems more logical - especially if you are talking about **historical data**)

Comment: @KenLee initially it was linked to User. then I want the data to be able to get updated and both the previous data and current data is stored. hence the reason why there are 2 comments on the code

Comment: @KenLee the idea is that the current data will be transferred to the attendance_record table so that i can trace the changes that happen. the date_checkIn, time_checkIn, and location_checkIn will be coming from front-end(flutter) and updated at the User table and the current data in the User table is transferred to the attendance_records table and thus a history of the record is recorded

Comment: Can you check whether your current users (user) db table records contain the  `location_checkIn`, `time_checkIn` and `date_checkIn` data ? (or they are actually null ?)

Comment: @KenLee in the User table, they are null

Comment: @KenLee the User table contain location_checkIn, time_checkIn and date_checkIn but it is null

Comment: Most likely that the statement `$users->save();` fails. So each time you cannot update the user table, and so the AttendanceRecord table always filled with null values (because it depends on existing values in one user table record). Please check the statements / values passing to $users before you save it.

Comment: @KenLee I tried changing the position of '$users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;
        $users->save(); '

to above the comments of '//Retrieve current data' and now the data is stored in the attendance_record table. However, the data in the User table is still empty.

Comment: @KenLee I think this will do it for now. I gotta find a way on how to display the stored data now like a history record and also do the same for time_checkOut and location_checkOut

Answer (score 0):

You still need field id when updating the user data. You may change some of your select statement by add **'id'** into it :

```
$users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['id', 'staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();
```

After that, go to your AttendanceRecord model, add field id into guarded.

```
protected $guarded = ['id'];
```

After that, you can try it to run the endpoint again. It should be updated.

But if you don't want to add guarded into your AttendanceRecord model, you should change your code when retrieve current data into:

```
$currentData = [
        "staff_id" => $users->staff_id,
        "date_checkIn" => $users->date_checkIn,
        "time_checkIn" => $users->time_checkIn,
        "location_checkIn" => $users->location_checkIn,
    ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but rn it is working with the staff_id ..the info that is required is all recorded